# Combination of map and filter doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object like this.
I need to remove the elements in the feature array if `feature_id` value is present in an array I already have.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Display",
    "data": {
      "id": 34566,
      "category_id": 2647,
      "feature_group_id": 5
    },
    "features": [
      {
        "name": "Tipo di display",
        "data": {
          "id": 85325,
          "category_id": 2647,
          "feature_id": 9104,
          "category_feature_group_id": 34566,
          "order": 10100140
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Risoluzione del display",
        "data": {
          "id": 85332,
          "category_id": 2647,
          "feature_id": 1585,
          "category_feature_group_id": 34566,
          "order": 10100130
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Touch screen",
        "data": {
          "id": 85331,
          "category_id": 2647,
          "feature_id": 4963,
          "category_feature_group_id": 34566,
          "order": 10100129
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Tipo di vetro",
        "data": {
          "id": 94704,
          "category_id": 2647,
          "feature_id": 7610,
          "category_feature_group_id": 34566,
          "order": 100050
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Design",
    "data": {
      "id": 16293,
      "category_id": 2647,
      "feature_group_id": 148
    },
    "features": [
      {
        "name": "Colore struttura",
        "data": {
          "id": 85298,
          "category_id": 2647,
          "feature_id": 10059,
          "category_feature_group_id": 16293,
          "order": 10100090
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Materiale della scocca",
        "data": {
          "id": 85300,
          "category_id": 2647,
          "feature_id": 5214,
          "category_feature_group_id": 16293,
          "order": 10100089
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Colore cinturino",
        "data": {
          "id": 85301,
          "category_id": 2647,
          "feature_id": 11025,
          "category_feature_group_id": 16293,
          "order": 10100080
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Materiale cinturino",
        "data": {
          "id": 94551,
          "category_id": 2647,
          "feature_id": 7605,
          "category_feature_group_id": 16293,
          "order": 100160
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I write this, where `featureIds` is my array and structure is the object

```
      structure.map((object) => {
        object.features.filter(feature => {
          this.featureIds.includes(feature.data.id)
        })
      })
```

In the result I still have a lot of features where ID is not in my array. Where is the error?

Comment: `includes` does not add/push to array, just check if the item is in the array. in your case, it is only checking if `feature.data.id` in `this.featureIds`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. The main one is that `filter` **returns** the new array with the filter applied, it doesn't change the array you call it on. You're not using that new array for anything. The other is that `map` does the same thing, it returns a **new** array with the mapped values, it doesn't modify the array you call it on.

If you want to filter the `features` array of all of the objects in the array, you have a couple of options, but both involve using the return value of things that filter/map arrays:

1. Update the objects in place

   ```
   for (const object of structure) {
       object.features = object.features.filter(feature => this.featureIds.includes(feature.data.id));
   }
   ```
2. Create new objects and a new array:

   ```
   structure = structure.map(object => ({
       ...object,
       features: object.features.filter(feature => this.featureIds.includes(feature.data.id))
   }));
   ```

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. Basically the filter works but the array returned is not used in my map, so I don't change anything. Thank you!